# LDAP Authentication in classic asp

Tags: vbscript, asp-classic, ldap

I have LDAP Authentication for my ASP site. Code is working fine on Windows 2003 Server. However we need to migrate our application to Windows 2012 R2 server.Unfortunately, the same is not working Error comes as "Server is not in operational."

Below is my code. Kindly advise for the same

```
Function AuthUser(strFSUID, strPwd)

    Const ADS_FAST_BIND_SSL = 34 'forces fast binding and SSL connection
    Const strADSPath =
    "LDAP://mdsoti.fsu.edu:636/ou=People,dc=fsu,dc=edu" 'full path to LDAP server
    Const strProxyUser = "proxy-user" 'proxy username For establishing initial connection to LDAP
    Const strProxyPass = "proxy-pass" 'proxy password For establishing initial connection To LDAP

    Dim conADODB 'LDAP admin connection
    Dim comADODB 'User DB connection
    Dim rsLDAP 'recordset to hold user information
    Dim dsoLDAP 'LDAP system object
    Dim conUser 'LDAP connection to validate username and password
    Dim strPath 'users FQDN path
    Dim strUser 'users dn stripped from ADsPath
    Dim blnAuthenticated 'has user been authenticated: 0 = no, -1 = yes

    On Error Resume Next
    blnAuthenticated = False

    'Create our admin connection for retrieving user DN
    Set conADODB = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    conADODB.Provider = "ADsDSOObject"
    conADODB.Properties("user ID") = "cn=" & strProxyUser & ",ou=proxy-users,dc=fsu,dc=edu"
    conADODB.Properties("Password") = strProxyPass
    conADODB.Properties("ADSI Flag") = ADS_FAST_BIND_SSL

    conADODB.Open "ADSI"

    'next we get the users dn
    Set comADODB = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
    Set comADODB.ActiveConnection = conADODB
    comADODB.CommandText = "<" & strADSPath & ">;(cn=" & strFSUID & ");Adspath,cn,;subtree"
    Set rsLDAP = comADODB.Execute

    'finally, we validate the actual username and password
    While Not (rsLDAP.EOF)
        strPath = rsLDAP.fields("ADsPath")
        wscript.echo strPath

        'strip out user dn from ADsPath
        strUser = InStrRev(strPath, "/")
        strUser = Mid(strPath, strUser + 1)
        wscript.echo strUser

        'open connection to authenticate users FSUID and password
        Set dsoLDAP = GetObject("LDAP:")
        Set conUser = dsoLDAP.OpenDSObject(strADSPath, strUser, strPwd, ADS_FAST_BIND_SSL)

        'see if the user's password worked. if not print error message 
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
           blnAuthenticated = False
        Else
           blnAuthenticated = True
        End If

        v = rsLDAP.fields("cn")
        wscript.echo v(0)

        rsLDAP.MoveNext
    Wend

    AuthUser = blnAuthenticated
End Function
```

Error comes while executing "Set rsLDAP = comADODB.Execute"

Thanks in adavance

Comment: Try the following code on the Windows 2012 server command line?  telnet mdsoti.fsu.edu 636

Comment: can connect through telnet... I think there is issue with SSl certificates